# How is SQL Server evaluating this query with a smalldatetime value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following demonstration queries and the results (note the only difference in the two queries is the comparison operator in the WHERE clause):

[image]

The LUpd_DateTime column is a smalldatetime data type. Since the smalldatetime data type doesn't actually contain any seconds (rounding occurs up or down to the nearest minute), the only explanation I have for the two queries below is that SQL Server is converting the date string to a smalldatetime type and rounding up to the nearest minute, thus changing the date string to '9/20/2018 00:00:00 AM'.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL Server is converting the date string to a smalldatetime type and
>   rounding up to the nearest minute, thus changing the date string to
>   '9/20/2018 00:00:00 AM'. Can anyone confirm this?

Yes.  To compare two expressions SQL Server always converts both expressions to a common data type.  Whichever expression's data type has the lower [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is converted.  The "date string" is an expression of type `varchar` which has a lower precedence than `smalldatetime`.  So the string is converted to smalldatetime for comparison.  And you can verify that the conversion rounds to the nearest value:

```
select cast( '2018-09-19 11:59:59' as smalldatetime)
```

outputs

```
2018-09-19 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have mistyped your explanation? You state that the column is a smalldatetime but then go on to say you think the query is converting the "date string to a smalldatetime". If what I said is correct, then a simple check of logic will show your assumption to be true. Yes, when converting it will become "09/20/2018 00:00:00 AM".

```sql
DECLARE @dateField AS date
SET @dateField = '2018-09-20 06:23:00'
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, @dateField)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is covered clearly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day. The time is based
>   on a 24-hour day, with seconds always zero (:00) and without
>   fractional seconds.

If you look at your results all are 00 seconds.